# adding a simple "$" to a dynamic UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

Forgive me if this is a basic question, i'm learning objective-C and iphone programming and I want to do a simple UILabel that displays a balance.  There is a UITextField and a Submit Button for the user to enter a balance.  Once the user hits submit, the UILabel would display the new balance.

My problem:
Users enter in a number only (e.g. "500") but I want the UILabel to display a default dollar ($) infront of it. (e.g. "$500")

In my implementation I had used this code:

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    self.balance.text = self.balanceTextField.text;
}
```

when i try to add an NSLog option to force the display as a string:
 self.balanceTextField.text = NSLog(@"$%@", balanceTextField)

Xcode gives me the error that i'm trying invoke a string type from a Void type.

How could I solve this issue and have that dollar sign automatically appear in my UILabel?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

NSLog is a logging method—it’s not a generic “format a string like this” method. What you’re looking for is `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

```
self.balance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", self.balanceTextField.text];
```

As JB13 points out, though, you might want to use an [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1) to format the text for you.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks, I'll use the currency numberFormatter option though since it gives me the 2 decimal places too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about a helper Method to Format to Currency and not just the $ sign

```
- (NSString *)currencyFormatFromNumber:(NSNumber*)number
{
    NSString *output = nil;
    if (number != nil)
    {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

        output = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
            formatter = nil;
    }

    return output;
}
```

…

```
self.balance.text = [self CurrencyFormatFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.balanceTextField.text doubleValue]]];
```

Comment: The advice to use a number formatter is correct, however there doesn't seem to be any reason for this to be  a method rather than a function (or just inline with OP's code. It should also not start with a capital letter -- only type names should. Further, it's not necessary to set the formatter to `nil`; it will be released by ARC at the end of the method in any case.

Answer (score 0):

the two most common ways of doing this ***(with slight correction, what if the string is nil?)*** is:

(1)

```
  self.balance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", self.balanceTextField.text?self.balanceTextField.text:@"0"];
```

(2)

```
self.balance.text = [@"$" stringByAppendingString: self.balanceTextField.text?self.balanceTextField.text:@"0"];
```